# PHP/Javascript - Google Graphs Causing Loop Error (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, graph, charts

Okay guys so I have this error coming up in my server errors and its being caused by Google Graph I have displayed on one of the pages of my site. After some time with the graph loaded on the page this loops out of control and the server runs out of memory and i get major I/O errors on my cPanel.

```
[22-Oct-2014 19:14:23 UTC] PHP Warning:  fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/gift3dsaint/public_html/graph.php on line 44  
[22-Oct-2014 19:14:23 UTC] PHP Warning:  feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/gift3dsaint/public_html/graph.php on line 42  
[22-Oct-2014 19:14:23 UTC] PHP Warning:  fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/gift3dsaint/public_html/graph.php on line 44  
[22-Oct-2014 19:14:23 UTC] PHP Warning:  feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/gift3dsaint/public_html/graph.php on line 42  
[22-Oct-2014 19:14:23 UTC] PHP Warning:  fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/gift3dsaint/public_html/graph.php on line 44  
[22-Oct-2014 19:14:23 UTC] PHP Warning:  feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/gift3dsaint/public_html/graph.php on line 42
```

The code I have referencing to the graph is this PHP:

```
 $lines=array();
 $fp = fopen($file, "r");
 while(!feof($fp)) {
      $line = fgets($fp, 4096);
      array_push($lines, $line);
 }
 fclose($fp);
```

Comment: $file open failed debug that; only post relevant code next time please.

Comment: $file open failed debug that.  Can you elaborate please?

Comment: `fgets` is complaining about `$fp` not being a resource. `$fp` should be a resource retuned from `fopen` but as its a boolean, `fopen` failed and returned a boolean error not a resource. `fopen` is trying to open the file `$file` so that's where the problem is.